# Backing up from local repo to a remote services such as Bitbucket

Tags: git, backup, bitbucket

I want to use a repo on a remote git service as a backup for a locally created repo. The remote service is namely Bitbucket, but the question can apply to others.

I can't create a bare repo on Bitbucket (or can I?) so I don't know how to work with 'push --mirror'.

Pushing all branches and commits is sort of ok, but we want to push as much more as possible, such as:
tags, remote pointers, remote branches - so that if we clone back downstream, we get a clone that is close enough to the original local repo without the need for too much re-wiring.

We are not concerned about uncommitted work or the working directory or staging area. The workflow is to do a commit then follow by a push to the backup.

We are not seeking a perfect clone that covers working and staging areas. Also we are not seeking a bullet proof backup, I understand that branches can be deleted on local and lost on remote. So basically this is about an easy way to do a partial backup to a service that is already there and providing free private accounts - which 
provides some level of redundancy and thus some piece of mind.

How can I achieve the above.

**First Edit:**

This is a log of first trial - not what I expected from my all-local tests, but this in what I'm getting:

- create repo on Bitbucket:

> ```
> https://shishani@bitbucket.org/shishani/test1.git
> ```

- local session

> ```
> $ git remote add bbtest1  https://shishani@bitbucket.org/shishani/test1.git
>
> $ git status
> # On branch master
> nothing to commit (working directory clean)
>
> $ git branch -a
> * master
>   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
>   remotes/origin/master
>
> $ git remote -v
> bbtest1   https://shishani@bitbucket.org/shishani/test1.git (fetch)
> bbtest1   https://shishani@bitbucket.org/shishani/test1.git (push)
> origin    /more/coding/git-tests/test-orig (fetch)
> origin    /more/coding/git-tests/test-orig (push)
>
>
> $ git push --mirror  bbtest1 
> Password: 
> fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :capabilities^{}
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> ```

Any idea what's going on ?!

**Second Edit:**

I forked a separate question for the unexpected error message here: 
[fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :capabilities^{}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247472/fatal-remote-part-of-refspec-is-not-a-valid-name-in-capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used BitBucket, but the process will be more or less equivalent with any of these hosting providers:

Create the remote repository.  (eg: `test`)

Add it as a remote to git:

```
# these paths should be accurate, but check your repo provider
git add remote bitbucket https://you@bitbucket.org/you/test.git
git add remote github git@github.com:you/test.git
```

Push to it:

```
git push bitbucket --mirror
git push github --mirror
```

Comment: Thanks, please check my edit - I meant to reproduce my all-local tests, but I'm getting something new unexpected with Bitbucket.

Comment: I suspect a local ref has a name that the remote isn't accepting, but I can't tell why.  There is something odd in the local repository, though, since the steps you followed should have worked.  I would suggest pushing each ref in turn, to find out which one is bad.